# Does ClockworkMod Recovery's "Wipe Data" command also wipe the SD card?

Tags: sd-card, clockworkmod-recovery

I've been playing with rooting and custom ROMs for a while now. I'm fairly comfortable and knowledgable about it all. However there is one thing I haven't really found the answer for nor have I gotten a chance to test for myself to answer it.

When you use the "Wipe Data" command in ClockworkMod Recovery, does it also format the SD card?

Comment: Logically, it wouldn't make sense for it to also format the SD card because the user would be stuck with no OS to install UNLESS they assume the user "knows" to pull out the SD card before wiping data (which I've been doing)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it does not format the SD card.  It only wipes all internal memory on the phone.  It is recommended you do this every time you switch to a new CustomRom, or if the current CustomRom is giving you problems (typically after upgrading the CustomRom).

Comment: Thanks. I suspected as much but I wanted confirmation rather than assumptions. =)

Comment: does this include all of the installed apps?  Does it include the data for the installed apps?

Comment: Yes, it will wipe installed applications.