# Will the 'wipe data/factory reset' option in clockworkdmod also wipe the internal sd card?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, factory-reset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does ClockworkMod Recovery's “Wipe Data” command also wipe the SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/does-clockworkmod-recoverys-wipe-data-command-also-wipe-the-sd-card)

I've been using non wipe roms and I'm planning to do a full wipe, my backups etc are on the internal sd card.

Does the above option in cwm also wipe the internal sd card?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

No.

This would make no sense, because the main use of wiping from ClockworkMod is to install a new ROM from SD card. As certain devices (e.g., Nexus S) do not have an external SD card, wiping the internal storage marked as "SD card" would wipe the ROM you are about to install.